# SVG validation in Java

Tags: java, validation, svg, groovy

Is there a way or code snippet by using which we can do SVG code validation in java or groovy?

The code should check if the wrong SVG code is uploaded.

E.g.: **Below code does not have closing symbol tag (`</symbol>`) so should through error at time of saving data from form.**

```
<symbol id="sym01" viewBox="0 0 150 110">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="8"
      stroke="red" fill="red"/>
  <circle cx="90" cy="60" r="40" stroke-width="8"
      stroke="green" fill="white"/>
```

Comment: Any XML parser can validate that something is valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy, just trying to parse the fragment with XmlSlurper will fail if it's not well formed e.g.

```
def badXml = '''<symbol id="sym01" viewBox="0 0 150 110">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="8"
      stroke="red" fill="red"/>
  <circle cx="90" cy="60" r="40" stroke-width="8"
      stroke="green" fill="white"/>'''

def x = new XmlSlurper().parseText( badXml )
```

will throw following exception:

> Caught: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber:
>   36; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.